# Need to cache some static images in a Multi Instance environment

Tags: java, apache, docker, http, caching

We have an java application with multiple instances running inside a docker instance (Multiple app instances can also run on multiple docker instances). Several clients when restarted hit our application (http calls) and fetch several images, most of these images are static. What will be the best approach to cache these images in order to reduce multiple disk operations.

PS - The application runs on Apache tomcat. Its kind of a POC. Is there solution around Apache httpd (don't have much idea about it). Or will it be good if every instance has its own cache, Or creating a shared docker volume can be a solution?

Comment: Yes, create shared docker volume is the suggest way. BTW, what `POC` mean? I by chance see this vocabulary days ago.

Comment: @atline POC is usually Proof-of-Concept.

Comment: There are many ways and it depends on tech stack or the platform. if AWS, I would recommend cloud front / S3 for hosting static website. How about using some object storage like S3 ?. [S3 on docker](https://min.io/) or something equivalent storage drivers